# How can I group on a nested property as well as having the same parent in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to `LINQ`, and I'm having trouble organizing this query to return what I want. First off, some background. I'm working on a music game, which supports custom notecharts. Notecharts contain metadata specific to a collection of notes, such as number of notes, difficulty, and BPM. One or more notecharts can be in a simfile, sort of a container of notecharts. A simfile has its own "simfile-level" metadata as well, such as a path to a song file, song title, song artist, etc. So, I have classes of the following form:

```
class Notechart {
    public List<Note> Notes { get; }
    public uint BPM { get; set; }
    public uint Difficulty { get; set; }
}

class Simfile {
    public List<Notechart> Notecharts { get; }
    public string SongPath { get; set; }
    public string SongTitle { get; set; }
    public string SongArtist { get; set; }
    // Other "album-specific" fields...
}
```

For a given `List<Simfile>`, I'd like to get a list of all `Notecharts` contained in all the `Simfiles` grouped by the following criteria (in order of precedence):
  1) The value of `Notechart.<Value>`, where `<Value>` is any of the notechart-specific fields or a transformation of a notechart-specific field (e.g. any BPMs between 130-150)
  2) Being in the same `Simfile` (since if two notecharts within a simfile have the same criteria as above, I would want to display them together with information from the simfile)

Is there anyway to represent this in `LINQ`? `MyElement` and `MyElementCollection` don't implement any custom equality checking, so I don't believe testing if it is in the list will work. Thanks!